# How to start video view when buffering reaches percentage that i want (20%) android

Tags: android, video, media-player, android-videoview, buffering

I want to stream video from url.When buffer reached 20% i want to start video in the same moment.Here is my code...

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       final VideoView vidView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
       MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
       vidControl.setAnchorView(vidView);
       vidView.setMediaController(vidControl);


       String vidAddress = "http://d38e3g3vk5nrvg.cloudfront.net/1452268197713.mp4";

       Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
       vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
       vidView.start();

       vidView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

               mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i) {
                       Log.d(TAG, "onBufferingUpdate: " + i);
                       if (i >= 20) {
                           Log.d(TAG, "onBufferingUpdate: >= 20");
                           vidView.start();

                       }
                   }
               });

            }
        });
   }
```

The problem is when buffering reach 20% video didn't start ... start when reached 50% every time... but this is too much waiting for users when video is bigger.Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you find any solution then please post answer, i also facing same promblem.

Comment: For this problem exactly no... But i use vitamio library and i do not have any problem with buffering.